# Requests between docker containers on same host using the public IP

Tags: networking, docker, bridge, iproute2, docker-networking

I have a server with Docker and some containers executing. The host has a public ip and a service listening on port 80 from one of the containers.

If I try to wget the service using the public ip from the host it works correctly, but if I try to wget the service with the same public ip from the other container it gets timeout error.

**ip route** gets me the following:

```
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-bbfbb2af08f1 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
***.***.***.***/** dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src ***.***.***.*** (public ip rule)
```

On my host the ifconfig has interface eth0 with public ip on the inet field.

On my other container the ifconfig has interface eth0 with container ip on bridge network.

I do not want to use the host network for my containers. I cannot use the internal name to communicate between containers.

I want the containers to communicate as if they are connected to internet, using the public ip and public url, ignoring that they are on same server.

I already checked other related questions but I have not found a valid solution for my problem.

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you connect to other public websites from within the container? Also curious why you want to go over Internet instead of using the private network.

Comment: the usually way of a request would be: client -> host -> VM for a IPv4 packet. how do you wanna skip this?

Comment: The two services are not linked and not related, so it has no sense to link them on private network. The first service uses the second as a common service on the web.

Comment: I would not to skip the IPv4  request flow, but the client is a different container on same host. If I do a request to public ip from the host it understand the request point on his machine and all works. But if the request starts from a container it skips this...

Comment: The term you are looking for is "hairpin nat" and it often requires additional setup. it may be easier to setup the containers on a shared network and just setup a network alias if you can't use the container name.

Comment: Thank you, I think the solution is hairpin nat. I'm searching about how to implement it with host and different docker networks. Shared network is not a solution in my environment. I could change host and docker configuration.